# Match function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that returns the third lowest value. It skips blanks but includes 0s, which is exactly what I want. When I use the formula regularly (or as an array) on a worksheet it works. But the same function doesn't work in VBA.

```
Example:
=MATCH(SMALL(E3:O3,3),E3:O3,FALSE) in the worksheet does the following
{1,2,3,blank,5} returns the value 3
{1,2,3,0,5} returns the value 2

wf.Match(wf.Small(aDivs, i), aDivs, False) in VBA does the following
{1,2,3,blank,5} returns the value 2
{1,2,3,0,5} returns the value 2
(aDivs is a calculation stored in an array)
```

It worked fine before, but because there is the possibility now to fill in the cells non-sequentially, I need this part to skip blanks. How can I get the VBA function to work like the worksheet function? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim vaNums As Variant, vaDenoms As Variant, aDivs() As Double
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim lSmall As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim rStart As Range
Dim iCount As Integer
Const lCols As Long = 10
Const lMarkcnt As Long = 3
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set rRow = Target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, lCols)
Set rStart = Me.Cells(1, 5)
iCount = wf.CountA(rRow, ">0")
If Not Intersect(Target.Cells(1), Me.Range("D3", Me.Range("D3").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing Then
If iCount > 4 Then
    Set rRow = Target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, iCount - 1)
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    vaNums = rRow.Value
    vaDenoms = rStart.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, lCols).Value
    ReDim aDivs(LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2))
    For i = LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2)
        aDivs(i) = vaNums(1, i) / vaDenoms(1, i) + (i / 10000)
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 3
        lSmall = wf.Match(wf.Small(aDivs, i), aDivs, False)
        rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Interior.Color = 6299648
        rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    Next i
Else
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If
Else
rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I Tried this, and, if values came from a Excel range, it works:

```
Function GetSmall3(ByRef MyRange As Range)
Dim v, x, y
v = MyRange
x = Application.Small(v, 3)
y = Application.Match(x, v, 0)
GetSmall3 = y
End Function
```

If you're using an excel array, I think it will depend how you refer to the empty value.
I used an empty string and still works, you need an array of variants

```
Dim v, x, y
v = Array(1, 2, 3, "", 5)
x = Application.Small(v, 3)
y = Application.Match(x, v, 0)
msgbox y
```

This is similar to your last code and works

```
Sub Try()
Dim i As Integer, vanums, aDivs, rRow, wf
Dim lSmall
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set rRow = Range("A1:J1")
vanums = rRow
ReDim aDivs(LBound(vanums, 2) To UBound(vanums, 2))
For i = LBound(vanums, 2) To UBound(vanums, 2)
        If IsEmpty(vanums(1, i)) Then
            aDivs(i) = Empty
        Else
            aDivs(i) = vanums(1, i)
        End If
Next i
For i = 1 To 3
    lSmall = wf.Match(wf.Small(aDivs, i), aDivs, False)
    MsgBox lSmall
Next
End Sub
```

Values in A1:J1 {1,2,3,empty,5,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty}

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. It might help if I put the code I'm trying to work with:

Comment: I actually need the lowest three.

Comment: I see, How can you get an empty value in aDivs, it seems all the elements are the result of a math operation...

Comment: I see what you're saying. That's right. Is it possible to not calculate if the cell in rRow is blank?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. I get a 'type mismatch" for: ADivs(i)=""

Comment: aDvis should be an array of variants, not doubles...if aDivs is an array of doubles you cannot have a blank element

Comment: I changed it to a variant data type and the following still doesn't work: For i = LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2)
        If IsEmpty(rRow) Then aDivs(i) = "" Else
            aDivs(i) = vaNums(1, i) / vaDenoms(1, i) + (i / 10000)
        Next i

Comment: Hum....rRow is a range right? so I think it is rRow(1,i) or as you copied rRow to the vaNums array IsEmpty(vaNums(1,i))

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why this isn't working. rRow is a range (resized according to iCount). I tried IsEmpty(...(1,i)) with both rRow and vaNums. It still highlights 1st,2nd,4th from {1,2,3,blank,5}.

Comment: Try to see what is the value in aDivs(4) in the end, follow the code, step by step, to see if, when i=4, you store an empty string...In my examples, you can see, that empty string is ignored by the small function...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED...Finally!!!

```
Dim i As Long
Dim vaNums As Variant, vaDenoms As Variant, aDivs() As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim lSmall As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim rStart As Range
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim lRows As Integer
Dim lCols As Long
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
lCols = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(1, 5).Offset(0, ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns.Count - 11)).Count
Set rRow = target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, lCols)
Set rStart = Me.Cells(1, 5)
iCount = wf.CountA(rRow, ">0")
If Not Intersect(target.Cells(1), Me.Range("D3", Me.Range("D3").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing Then
If iCount > 4 Then
    Set rRow = target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, lCols)
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    vaNums = rRow.Value
    vaDenoms = rStart.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, lCols).Value
    ReDim aDivs(LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2))
    For i = LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2)
            If IsEmpty(vaNums(1, i)) Then
                aDivs(i) = Empty
            Else
                aDivs(i) = vaNums(1, i) / vaDenoms(1, i) + (i / 10000)
            End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 3
        lSmall = wf.Match(wf.Small(aDivs, i), aDivs, False)
        rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Interior.Color = 6299648
        rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    Next i
Else
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If
Else
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    rStart.Resize(1, lCols).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End If

End Sub
```